# Key exists in dict, but still reporting a KeyError

Tags: python, sympy, keyerror

I found a strange error in Python. The key exists in the dict, but it's still reporting a KeyError. The key exists in list(dict), but key does not exist in dict, why?

This is the code:

```py
check_key = (predicate, item)
print(type(predicate))
print(type(item))
print(type(self.id_of_item))
print()
print("check_key: {}".format(check_key))
print("self.id_of_item: {}".format(self.id_of_item))
print("list(self.id_of_item): {}".format(list(self.id_of_item)))
print()
print("check_key in self.id_of_item?            {}".format(check_key in self.id_of_item))
print("check_key in list(self.id_of_item)?      {}".format(check_key in list(self.id_of_item)))
print("check_key == list(self.id_of_item)[-1]?  {}".format(check_key == list(self.id_of_item)[-1]))
```

This is the output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
<class 'dict'>

check_key: ('Equation', ll_bc - 4.0)
self.id_of_item: {('Equation', ll_bc - 4.0): 87}
list(self.id_of_item): [('Equation', ll_bc - 4.0)]

check_key in self.id_of_item?            False
check_key in list(self.id_of_item)?      True
check_key == list(self.id_of_item)[-1]?  True
```

How can I modify my code to access values through the key 'check_key'?

This problem is difficult to reproduce. I wrote a mathematical problem-solving program using the library SymPy, and only one error was reported for 6 thousands of problems. So it's impossible to provide a program that can run directly, I can provide more output.

This is the newly added code:

```py
print("id(check_key): {}".format(id(check_key)))
print("id(list(self.id_of_item)[-1]): {}".format(id(list(self.id_of_item)[-1])))
print("check_key is list(self.id_of_item)[-1]?   {}".format(check_key is list(self.id_of_item)[-1]))
```

This is the new output:

```
id(check_key): 2795752447488
id(list(self.id_of_item)[-1]): 2795752487168
check_key is list(self.id_of_item)[-1]?   False
```

It seems that the problem has been solved. `check_key` and `list(self.id_of_item)[-1]` have different id. I need to learn more about the difference between 'is' and '=='.

However, the `id` is not the only issue! I added minimum runnable code to prove this. Although the `id` of `eq1` and `eq2` are different, they all map to the same location in the dictionary.

```py
python==3.10.9
sympy==1.10.1

from sympy import symbols
ll_bc = symbols("ll_bc")
eq1 = ll_bc + 1.5 - 5.5
eq2 = ll_bc - 4.0
a_dict = {eq1: 1}
print("eq1: {}".format(eq1))
print("eq2: {}".format(eq2))
print("a_dict: {}".format(a_dict))
print()
print("eq1 is eq2: {}".format(eq1 is eq2))
print("eq1 == eq2: {}".format(eq1 == eq2))
print("eq2 in a_dict?: {}".format(eq2 in a_dict))
print("eq2 in list(a_dict)?: {}".format(eq2 in list(a_dict)))
```

output:

```
eq1: ll_bc - 4.0
eq2: ll_bc - 4.0
a_dict: {ll_bc - 4.0: 1}

eq1 is eq2: False
eq1 == eq2: True
eq2 in a_dict?: True
eq2 in list(a_dict)?: True
```

I finally reproduced the problem. This is an error caused by the precision problem of the float number. The minimum runnable code is as follows:

```py
python==3.10.9
sympy==1.10.1
from sympy import symbols, Float


def float_round(n, round_it=True):
    if round_it:
        return n.round(6)
    return n


a = symbols("a")
target = a + float_round(Float(1.1))
eq1 = a - 1.0
eq2 = target - float_round(target.subs(a, 1.0))
a_dict = {eq1: 1}
print("eq1: {}".format(eq1))
print("eq2: {}".format(eq2))
print("eq1 is eq2?: {}".format(eq1 is eq2))
print("eq1 == eq2?: {}".format(eq1 == eq2))
print("eq2 in a_dict?: {}".format(eq2 in a_dict))
print("eq2 in list(a_dict)?: {}".format(eq2 in list(a_dict)))
```

The output:

```
eq1: a - 1.0
eq2: a - 1.0
eq1 is eq2?: False
eq1 == eq2?: True
eq2 in a_dict?: False
eq2 in list(a_dict)?: True
```

`eq1` and `eq2` appear to be the same, but in fact they differ in float number.This may be caused by my incorrect use of the related functions of the library Sympy. I find that the value of `target.subs(a, 1.0)` is `2.09999999403954`. The correct value should be `2.1`. We can set `round_it` int function `float_round` to `True` then the problem disappears.
But I still learn a lot from this error. Obviously, operation 'in' is implemented using different methods in 'dict.keys()' and 'list'. I need to further learn.

Comment: Please make a working example of your code and include all the necessary code to run it. A good start would be the actual dict you are referring to.

Comment: Check the two "item" values.  They appear to be class instances, so even though they print the same, they may be different instances, and so will not compare as equal (unless you overloaded equality comparison).  Try looking at `id(item)` and `id(list(self.id_of_item)[0])`.  If the id values differ, then you have your answer.

Comment: We can only assume that `item` is `sympy.symbols('ll_bc') - 4.0`, but I am unable to replicate your issue - please include a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - emphasis on **verifiable** - if there is no way for others to replicate your issue, then it's not an issue others can begin to construct an answer for you.

Comment: The `id` is not the _only_ issue, the underlying `__hash__` for whatever reason might not have hashed the same for the `item` object. I would be very much interested if you can figure out how to reproduce this issue because something _might_ in fact be broken.

Comment: @metatoaster
Yes! I also found out that the id is not the only issue!! I am doing my best to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't expect floats to match with == or `is`. In numpy code we compare floats with `isclose` which checks that the numeric difference is small.  Be extra careful with floats in sympy expressions.

Comment: Printing `hash()` for `eq1` and `eq2` shows different values, even though they compare equal. [That is going to confuse dicts and sets](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)... I’ll leave the "why" to the sympy experts. Looks like a bug to me, but I have negligible experience with sympy.

Comment: You can probably post your own answer, I've reopened this.  I did have an inkling that it _might_ be float but the equivalence being the confusion point, though I wasn't able to reproduce the issue.  Please do post your own answer to this once you conclude your research.

Comment: It seems that the equations implement an equality operator which is not compatible with the hash. I would say this is a bug in simpy. It should either implement hash correctly or (preferably, I'd say) disable hash altogether. But then again, they probably don't want to cause backward compatibility issues by disabling hash now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have roughly understood what the problem is. I will first provide a more readable minimum runnable code and its output, and then comb through the reasons for this problem.
The code:

```py
python==3.10.9
sympy==1.10.1
from sympy import symbols, Float


def float_round(n, round_it=True):
    if round_it:
        return n.round(6)
    return n


a = symbols("a")
target = a + float_round(Float(1.1))
target_value = float_round(float_round(Float(1.1)) + 1)
print("different target_value:")
print(float_round(Float(1.1)) + 1)
print(float_round(Float(1.1)) + 1.0)
print(float_round(float_round(Float(1.1)) + 1))
print()

eq1 = target - target_value
eq2 = a - 1.0
print("eq1: {}".format(eq1))
print("eq2: {}".format(eq2))
print("hash(eq1): {}".format(hash(eq1)))
print("hash(eq2): {}".format(hash(eq2)))
print("eq1 is eq2?: {}".format(eq1 is eq2))
print("eq1 == eq2?: {}".format(eq1 == eq2))
print("hash(eq1) == hash(eq2)?: {}".format(hash(eq1) == hash(eq2)))
print()

a_dict = {eq1: 1}
print("a_dict: {}".format(a_dict))
print("eq1 == eq2?: {}".format(eq1 == eq2))
print("eq2 in a_dict?: {}".format(eq2 in a_dict))
print("eq2 in list(a_dict)?: {}".format(eq2 in list(a_dict)))
```

The output:

```
different target_value:
2.100000
2.09999999403954
2.100000

eq1: a - 1.0
eq2: a - 1.0
hash(eq1): 946170291633155547
hash(eq2): -2833311259663523353
eq1 is eq2?: False
eq1 == eq2?: True
hash(eq1) == hash(eq2)?: False

a_dict: {a - 1.0: 1}
eq1 == eq2?: True
eq2 in a_dict?: False
eq2 in list(a_dict)?: True
```

1. This is essentially the problem of the precision of float number.
   I constructed three float numbers with function `round` of the library SymPy. These three float numbers seem to be equivalent, but they are not. So the equation `eq1` constructed using `target_value` is also different from `eq2`, although their printed results are consistent.
2. I think this can be seen as a bug in SymPy.
   In the output of the second part, we can see that `eq1==eq2`. But `eq1` and `eq2` have different hash values. A quote from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons): "The `hash()` result should be consistent with equality. Objects that are equal should either have the same hash value, or be marked as unhashable."
3. Returning to the initial question. Why the key exists in list(dict), but key does not exist in dict?
   We need to understand the implementation of `in` in Python. A quote from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations): " For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`."
   More specifically, `in` is implemented in Python using the function `__contains__`. A quote from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__): "Called to implement membership test operators. Should return true if item is in self, false otherwise. For mapping objects, this should consider the keys of the mapping rather than the values or the key-item pairs."

`eq2 in list(a_dict)` is `True` because `eq1 == eq2`. `eq2 in a_dict` is `False` because `hash(eq1) != hash(eq2)`.

Comment: Um...It seems that there is still a need to supplement the specific implementation of `__contains__` in `dict`.  When searching in `dict`, is it based on the value of the key or the hash value of the key? I can't find any more detailed official documents.